# Azure Cognitive Services Speech to Text

Tags: azure, speech-to-text

I just transcribed an audio file with Azure Speech to Text. However, I used python and the Speech SDK of Azure but I was wondering if there was a more easier way to do this?

For example, I upload the audio file in the console, then a job is created where the audio file is transcribed and stored in Azure Storage and I can finally download it from there. For my usecase this would have been way faster.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the ingestion client which automatically transcribe audio files uploaded to a storage container. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/tree/master/samples/ingestion.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at batch transcription API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/batch-transcription
Thanks!

Comment: I actually did it with the batch transcription API. But I just wondered if there was an easier way, like the one in the console I described. If I only want to transcribe one file, this would be way better.